# Remote Contractor & Taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, contractor, brazil, income-tax

I'm not a US citizen (I studied there for over 10 years), and I'm currently living in my native south america. The company I used to work for in-house in the US now contracts with me, so that's been my full-time job since January 1, 2015. Should I file/pay income taxes in the US, my country, or both?

Answer (score 3):

You only pay taxes in Brazil, unless you're physically present in the US when you're performing the work.

Income for personal services is sourced to where you perform the services, and the US only taxes non-residents for income sourced to the US.

Comment: What about income I make from YouTube in the form of ad revenue? Is that taxable by the US in my case? Or do I just report that to Brazil as well?

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira are you making any work while in the US? It doesn't matter where your bank account is

Comment: What do you mean by making work? I haven't stepped foot in the US since Dec. 2014. The two companies that pay me are US based - my employer and Google (through AdSense). At my full-time job, I write software remotely. All from my home office in Brazil.

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira so why would you think you need to pay tax in the US? You don't.

Comment: @littleadv Answers like this would be better with some citations - both to make them good answers in general, but also to help people like me learn about the specifics.

Comment: @Joe how can a cite a negative?  Why would a person need to know the convoluted definitions of the US IRC just to know he/she is not subject to them?

Comment: I'm not the tax expert, but it took ten seconds to find [this page](https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/U.S.-Citizens-and-Resident-Aliens-Employed-Abroad-%E2%80%93-Employees) which (while not being generally relevant) has a paragraph at the bottom saying what you do above - I imagine there is a better page somewhere...

Comment: This is about wages and withholding, not taxes.